# Make cursor hover area larger

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

It is possible to make cursor area larger ? I am playing with hover event and i am wondering if it's possible to make the cursor "trigger" area larger.

[image]

When the invisible div touches my elemet i want to trigger hover event. Is this possible?

ps: the invisible div follows the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Then just apply the padding value for that element with higher value as you wish.

Or, if you wished to trigger the hover event after hovering some div, do like this:

```
$('.invDiv').hover(function(){
   $('.hovDiv').trigger('hover');
});
```

And your invisible div should not be hidden but instead use blank div and apply width and height for that area...